# GDALwarp converting data from 'Planar' to 'Geographic (degree)'

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I have a dataset in nc format (Daymet weather data) using gdal translate. I convert them to GeoTIFF, then using GDALwarp I try to change the coordinate system type to geographic because I want to have latitude and longitude. It does not give me the right lat and lon. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs "+proj=aea +datum=WGS72 +lat_1=25 n +lat_2=60n +lat_0=42.5n +lon_0=100w" NETCDF:"prcp_11742_2015.nc":prcp prcp_11742_2015_aea_lat.tif
```

then

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 prcp_11742_2015_aea_lat.tif prcp_11742_2015_aea_lat001.tif
```

the source file is in this format

```
The North American Daymet projection system and parameters: 
Projection System:  Lambert Conformal Conic
Parameters: 
projection units:   meters 
datum (spheroid):   WGS_84 
1st standard parallel:  25 deg N 
2nd standard parallel:  60 deg N 
Central meridian:   100 deg W
Latitude of origin: 42.5 deg N 
false easting:      0 
false northing:     0
```

---

The lcc is the projection of source file and i I wanted to change the projection to the equal distance area too that is why I used the proj =aea, also one problem i have is i want to have the lat/lon in the geotiff file but i do not see the right lat/lon in the geotiff file. the corners are as follow but after the conversion

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  158000.000,  -45000.000) ( 97d59'54.18"W, 42d 3'26.22"N)
Lower Left  (  158000.000, -263000.000) ( 98d 3'45.07"W, 40d 0' 2.98"N)
Upper Right (  326000.000,  -45000.000) ( 95d52'21.59"W, 41d59'56.50"N)
Lower Right (  326000.000, -263000.000) ( 96d 0'17.11"W, 39d56'40.19"N)
Center      (  242000.000, -154000.000) ( 96d59' 5.65"W, 41d 0'18.37"N)
```

i have this

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-126.0746130,  -0.4065400) (126d 4'28.61"W,  0d24'23.54"S)
Lower Left  (-126.0746130,  -2.3815368) (126d 4'28.61"W,  2d22'53.53"S)
Upper Right (-124.5595470,  -0.4065400) (124d33'34.37"W,  0d24'23.54"S)
Lower Right (-124.5595470,  -2.3815368) (124d33'34.37"W,  2d22'53.53"S)
Center      (-125.3170800,  -1.3940384) (125d19' 1.49"W,  1d23'38.54"S)
```

Comment: Just checking--why are you using WGS72 in gdal_translate? There's a space in the lat_1 specification (typo?). Can you edit your question with the extent you are getting versus what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

In both cases it has not sense to pass through another projection. You can use `gdalwarp` directly.

**lcc to wgs84:**

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=lcc +datum=WGS84 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:"prcp_11742_2015.nc":prcp prcp_11742_2015_lcc.tif
```

**lcc to aea(WGS72):**

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=lcc +datum=WGS84 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=aea +datum=WGS72 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +towgs84=0,0,4.5,0,0,0.554,0.2263 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:"prcp_11742_2015.nc":prcp prcp_11742_2015_aea.tif
```

(`+towgs84=0,0,4.5,0,0,0.554,0.2263` was missing)

considering:

```
Projection System:  Lambert Conformal Conic ==> +proj=lcc
Parameters: 
projection units:   meters                  ==> +units=m
datum (spheroid):   WGS_84                  ==> +datum=WGS84
1st standard parallel:  25 deg N            ==> +lat_1=25
2nd standard parallel:  60 deg N            ==> +lat_2=60
Central meridian:   100 deg W               ==> +lon_0=-100
Latitude of origin: 42.5 deg N              ==> +lat_0=42.5
false easting:      0                       ==> +x_0=0
false northing:     0                       ==> +y_0=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the lcc is the projection of source file and i I wanted to change the projection to the equal distance area too that is why I used the proj =aea, also one problem i have is i want to have the lat/lon in the geotiff file but i do not see the right lat/lon in the geotiff file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reproject, you have to use

```
gdalwarp -s_srs +proj=lcc ... -t_srs +proj=aea ...
```

whereas `gdaltranslate -a_srs +proj=aea` just assigns a wrong CRS without any reprojection.

If you want corner coordinates in degrees, you **must** use `-t_srs EPSG:4326`, and not any projected CRS.